# Issues with building an electron app with serialport

Tags: node.js, electron, node-serialport

I have been able to run a node.js app using serialport. Now trying to port it to electron for cross-platform use. 'npm install serialport' yielded the following:

```
  serialport@2.0.5 install /Users/ylh/0/electron/electron-quick-start-master/node_modules/serialport
  node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/serialport/src/serialport.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/serialport/src/serialport_unix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/serialport/src/serialport_poller.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/serialport.node
  COPY /Users/ylh/0/electron/electron-quick-start-master/node_modules/serialport/build/Release/node-v47-darwin-x64/serialport.node
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp

  electron-prebuilt@0.34.3 postinstall /Users/ylh/0/electron/electron-quick-start-master/node_modules/electron-prebuilt
  node install.js
```

When I ran the app with electron, the pop-up window complains that

```
The app provided is not a valid electron app, please read the docs on how to write one:
https://github.com/atom/electron/tree/master/docs

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/ylh/0/electron/electron-quick-start-master/node_modules/serialport/build/Release/node-v46-darwin-x64/serialport.node'
```

---

Sure enough, the version in the node_modules directory is node-v47-darwin-x64. I don't know why npm install builds v47 but looks for v46 to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export npm_config_disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell
export npm_config_target=0.34.3
export npm_config_arch=x64
export npm_config_runtime=electron
HOME=~/.electron-gyp npm install serialport
```

After this, go to `/Users/ylh/0/electron/electron-quick-start-master/node_modules/serialport/build/Release/`

And rename `electron-0.34-darwin-x64` to `node-v46-darwin-x64`

Comment: I got this: _$ HOME=~/.electron-gyp npm install serialport

> serialport@2.0.5 install /Users/ylh/0/electron/electron-quick-start-master/node_modules/serialport
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

Comment: try: `npm install -g node-pre-gyp`

Comment: Thanks - I got past the compile. Now need to debug my code ...  What you suggested seems a bit of black art. Care to explain? Especially the renaming.

Comment: When you use electron-gyp...serialport is compiled to electron engine, because this created electron-v0.34 folder. But, in serialport, your package.json   
use `"module_path": "./build/{configuration}/{node_abi}-{platform}-{arch}/"` as path to compiled file. `{node_abi}` always return `node` because pertence to `node-gyp`

Comment: if prefer...you can change only package.json in serialport folder...change `module_path` to `"module_path": "./build/{configuration}/"` and rebuild. If you make this, you don't need more rename release folder.